# Google finds Duplicate Title Tags

Tags: php, seo, duplicates

I have 2 issues regarding duplicate content.

I am using google webmasters and was notified that i have a few files with duplicate content.

Both are related to Duplicate Title Tags:

**ISSUE #1:  2 files:**
    (a) this is the correct file
    (b) this is the same file but with "?xxxx" after the filename

```
I do not know how to remove the (b) from the list, as it is not a real file, merely the 
same filename but attaching a tracking code to the end.  How do I remove?
```

**ISSUE #2:  2 files:**
    (a) this is the correct file
    (b) this same file, but with ".php" added to the end

```
I added a redirect script to .htaccess to remove the filename extension (.php) from the 
files so that it would load without the filename extension.  Now Google is telling me some 
are duplicate content.  How do I remove (b)?
```

Answer (score 0):

ISSUE #1: Google use "url"s to index pages not file address. so each url must represent a unique content. for instance "a.php?r=1" is different from "a.php?r=2" because urls are different. to solve this problem you can either do a 301 redirect (b) to (a) if they work totally similar or you can use [rel="canonical"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en)

ISSUE #1: you can use rel="canonical" too or if you are certainly sure that nobody can access (b) you can disregard the messages, they will be removed after a while.